# Maven project structure corrupted

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am building a Java Web Project (JAX-RS). Initially the project had the right structure. However after doing a maven clean and maven update the structure of the project seems to be corrupted in Eclipse.

Initially the layout was as follows:

```
-Root
    --src/main/java
    --src/test/java
    --..
```

After the clean-up the layout appears as:

```
-Root
    --src
        --main.java.com..<package1>
        --main.java.com..<package2>
        --...
    --src/test/java
    --..
```

Also now the whole project no longer builds. Any ideas as to how this can be fixed ?

Comment: What build error it is throwing?

Comment: It is giving errors with all the class references E.g. [ERROR]   symbol:   class Mapping
  location: class DataLoadScenario

Comment: Maven clean goal, clean everything. Run "clean install" it will first clean and then rebuild it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse sometimes behave oddly. I have found recreating the project from scratch is the best way when encountered a scenario like this.

To create project from scratch. Use `maven archtype`. Follow the link [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/).

Then copy your current sources over to the newly created projects.

Comment: Right. This is what I did finally !!

Comment: Can be made simpler. Delete the project from your workspace in Eclipse. Remove all folders `.settings` and the files `.project`, `.classpath` . Afterwards import the full project new into Eclipse.